# Traversing linked list and modifying or inserting node C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, nodes

I am attempting to write a function that will traverse a linked list, wherein the nodes represent terms of a polynomial. Each node includes fields for coefficient (a double named coeff), power (a size_t named power), and link (a NodePtr *next). The function is called with a double variable *value*, which represents the coefficient the node should have, and a size_t variable *i*, which represents its power. The function should traverse the linked list looking for the node with power *i*. If the list already contains a node with power i, its coefficient should be changed to hold the new value. If it did not previously have a node with power i, such a term should be added with the coefficient value. The list should be ordered by power (i.e. the node with power 3 should be the node 3 in the list).

Below is the code I have written thus far, though it currently generates the following error:

> > Unhandled exception at 0x0130D2FA in Project 3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000C.

I cannot figure out why the error is generated, so that is my first issue. The second is that I believe my function may have some logical errors and does not correctly modify and create new nodes.

I have been stumped on this for days and cannot test my other functions without this having this one in working order, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
void Poly::setCoeff(double value, size_t i)
{
    if (0 <= i){
        Node* prev = new Node();
        Node* curr = new Node();
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->coeff = value;
        newNode->power = i;
        curr = myHead;      // Initialize curr to myHead;
        if (curr != nullptr)
        {
            while (curr->next != nullptr && curr->power != i)
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            if (curr->power == i)
            {
                curr->coeff = value;
            }
            else if (curr->next == nullptr && i == curr->power + 1)
            {
                curr->next = new Node;  // Creates a node at the end of the list
                curr = curr->next; // Points to that node
                curr->next = nullptr; // Prevents it from going any further
                curr->power = i;
                curr->coeff = value;
            }
            else
            {

                prev->next = newNode;
                newNode->next = curr;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            curr->next = newNode;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to mention straight up that `curr->next = newNode` is *not* the thing to be doing when you just discovered `(curr != nullptr)` is **false**. The memory leak by first doing `Node* curr = new Node();`, then `curr = myHead;` is a bonus (similar problem with `prev`). This isn't Java.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the advice. I am in the beginning stages of learning C++ and have just switched over from Java, so I'm still pretty shaky. Could you possibly point me in the right direction for fixing this memory leak?

Comment: to fix the memories leak just replace Node* prev = new Node();Node* curr = new Node(); by  Node* prev,* curr ; and did you initialize some where in your code myHead by NULL? in java it stat by null but in c++ you have to do it myHead =NULL.

Comment: @Nea - `I am in the beginning stages of learning C++`  And the first thing you want to do is attempt to create a linked list?  Something that truly, only a high-intermediate or advanced C++ programmer could accomplish?  Also, it looks like your assignment is a Polynomial solver, not a linked list.

Comment: @Nea the only "right" direction is to first learn your debugging tools, then (1) learn how dynamic memory in C++ works, (2) learn the tools granted in the standard library that remove the need for you to implement a (1)-based solution in the first place, then (3) strive *heavily* to look for a solution in (2) before resorting to (1). A solution in (1) could be crafted in about 10 lines of code, in (2) with a single map-container, but neither will help until you spend more time on some fundamentals.

Comment: @Nea - Even with all this, you have to go and `delete` all of this memory, as C++ is not the same as Java in terms of "garbage collection".  IMO, this is not a beginner exercise -- I have yet to see a beginner code a linked list in C++ correctly without a mountain of help from experienced C++ programmers.

Comment: The best tools to find pointer problems is drawing them using pencil and paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a series of clear incorrect assumptions of how dynamic memory is managed in C++ that is getting you into heap-loads of trouble in this code. Were this not an academic exercise I would tell you simply to throw it **all** away and use:

```
std::map<size_t, double>
```

also known as: **The Good Stuff**. It would do literally everything you need this code to accomplish.

But this is academia. Like most things in academia they make you crawl through trenches before you learn how it *should* be. So, I will expose what is deficient in your code, but suffice it to say, once you learn all this you will **strive** not to have to do it in the first place by using tools already available to you.

In other words, unless someone said I had to do this with a hand-coded linked list implementation, I would use the above map instead. You can't (yet), but know it is there.

---

**Your Code**

You didn't include the definition of `Node`, but I can only assume it looks something like this:

```
struct Node
{
    double coeff;
    size_t power;
    Node *next;
};
```

Whether this is nested within `class Poly` or not (and it likely should be if the latter) is likewise unclear. It isn't entirely relevant to the question, but mentioned here to attempt to drive home that, when asking a question on SO, provide enough info to *minimize* assumptions that may affect the answers your getting.

With that your code:

```
void Poly::setCoeff(double value, size_t i)
{
    if (0 <= i)  // NOTE: not needed, unsigned, will always be i >= 0
    {
        Node* prev = new Node();     // NOTE: wrong. leaks memory.
        Node* curr = new Node();     // NOTE: same as above
        Node* newNode = new Node();  // NOTE: **may** leak (see below)
        newNode->coeff = value;
        newNode->power = i;
        curr = myHead;
        if (curr != nullptr) // OK: check for null good
        {
            // NOTE: should be checking `curr`, not curr->next
            while (curr->next != nullptr && curr->power != i)
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }

            // NOTE: should check curr for NULL first.
            if (curr->power == i)
            {
                curr->coeff = value;
            }

            // NOTE: same here. also, 
            else if (curr->next == nullptr && i == curr->power + 1)
            {
                // NOTE: this code path will leak newNode allocated at the
                //  top of the function.
                curr->next = new Node;
                curr = curr->next;
                curr->next = nullptr;
                curr->power = i;
                curr->coeff = value;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = newNode;
                newNode->next = curr;
            }
        }
        else
        {   // NOTE: this is where your mainline fault is coming from. you
            //  just validated curr can be NULL here (and will be on initial)
            curr->next = newNode;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    // NOTE: this can't happen, as i can never be less than zero
    else
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
}
```

The following are somewhat obvious.

- Your memory management is not correct, and includes introducing memory leaks.
- Your pointer management is likewise poor. Pointers are *not* like Java references, and *nothing* will get you in trouble faster in a C/C++ program than improper pointer management.
- The algorithm doesn't maintain the mandate the list be *ordered*.

---

**Changes to Your Code**

- The requirements for your code mandate an *ordered* list is maintained, yet your coefficient insertion algorithm makes no attempts at fulfilling that requirement. The `setCoeff` member is required to insert a new term if the matching exponent cannot be found, and if kept sorted, you'll know by proper enumeration whether that is the case by discovering (a) an exponent beyond yours, or (b) the end of the list, whichever happens *first*.
- `i` is a `size_t` value, which means it is a *magnitude* for object counting. The standard mandates `size_t` is *unsigned*, which means it cannot be negative. This means checking for `i >= 0` is useless. It will *always* be so.
- A new node is allocated before know you *need* one. Remember, this is supposed to update an *existing* node if you find a matching exponent entry. Only if there were *no* match should a new node be required.
- Your first-insert detection needs a complete redeux. It is guaranteed to invoke undefined behavior.

First make it easier on yourself. Provide a `Node` constructor that sets up a node via parameters so you can stop littering your code with that setup. In doing so, it becomes both easier to read and safer, since you initialize all member variables at *construction*.

```
struct Node
{
    Node *next;
    double coeff;
    size_t power;

    Node(double coeff_, size_t power_, Node *next_=nullptr)
        : coeff(coeff_), power(power_), next(next_)
    {}
};
```

With that, things will get considerably easier. The punch list above can be fulfilled with the following changes:

```
void Poly::setCoeff(double value, size_t i)
{
    Node *prev = nullptr; // points to prior node
    Node *curr = myHead;  // points to current node

    while (curr && curr->power < i)
    {
        prev = curr;         // remember current node...
        curr = curr->next;   // ... then move to next node
    }

    // only allocate a new node if
    //  (a) we reached the end of the list (curr == NULL)
    //  (b) we reached a node with non match (will be larger exponent)

    if (!curr || curr->power != i)
    {
        // **NOW** allocate the new node. we know we need one and we
        //  have a pretty solid idea where it goes.
        Node *newNode = new Node(value, i, curr);

        // if prev is set, then it means the new node goes somewhere
        //  *past* the head pointer otherwise it will become the new head.
        if (prev)
            prev->next = newNode;
        else
            myHead = newNode;
    }
    else
    {   // found matching node
        curr->coeff = value;
    }
}
```

I sincerely hope it helps, and wish you the best of luck in trenching through the cruft before you get to The Good Stuff. Its worth it in the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this was extremely helpful. As made quite obvious my code, I have been really struggling with managing memory and the implementation of linked lists (perhaps because we were expected to use them after only 50 mins of lecturing). Your response provided much needed clarity. Truth be told, your comments and explanations offered more insight into linked lists than both my professor and textbook combined. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I will follow up with the answer using a `std::map` (as WhozCraig's excellent answer mentions):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<size_t, double> Polynomial;

void AddCoefficientAndPower(Polynomial& poly, double coeff, size_t power)
{
    // This does everything your assignment asked for, except for implementing
    // all of that linked list stuff
    poly[power] = coeff;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Polynomial myPoly;

    // add the coefficient and power
    AddCoefficientAndPower(myPoly, 3, 1);
    AddCoefficientAndPower(myPoly, 4, 2);
    AddCoefficientAndPower(myPoly, 9, 0);
    AddCoefficientAndPower(myPoly, 6, 3);

    // This one will replace the previous (4,2) 
    AddCoefficientAndPower(myPoly, 3, 2);

    // write out the coefficients followed by the power
    Polynomial::iterator it = myPoly.begin();
    while (it != myPoly.end())
    {
        cout << it->second << "^" << it->first << "\n";
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9^0
3^1
3^2
6^3
```

Basically your entire assignment is a one line C++ statement in `AddCoefficent` that inserts an item in the map, and replaces an existing entry if one did exist.

Note -- no memory leaks, no calls to `new`, no crashes, etc.

Also, if your requirements were to also include any integral power value, then the above method works for negative, 0, and positive power values.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! Although WhozCraig was correct in his assumption that this project mandates we use the more tedious method, its clear std::map is the better approach and I will certainly try it out on my own. I appreciate you taking the time to explain this alternate answer to the problem, thanks again.

Comment: @Nea - This brings into question what the goal of the project is.  If it was to have you do a linked list, it would be far better if that was the focus -- build a linked list class.  If the focus is to build some sort of polynomial solver or some such, then the focus should be on that.  The issue I have is that teachers tend to jam up the works by having students implement data structures while at the same time have them code an application.  What happens is both a poor "inline" version of the data structure, and an app that doesn't work.